# Blender ViewPort Shading turns all white because of Eevee Lighting

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

When I change my viewport shading to Material Preview, everything turns black and red for a second and then all white. I am unable to see any textures or any shadows. The only remedy I was able to find was to switch my Render engine from Cycles to Eevee, bake the lighting, and then delete the lighting cache. Unfortunately, my blender crashes when I bake the lighting for Eevee..

Specs:
Blender 2.82
AMD 3600X
GTX 1070
16GB RAM DDR4
[image]

Comment: Can you share your .blend file for review? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: It's 48MB, heres a Google Drive link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LPOdWlGeUYGDhWZhwiyB3gOeMyCyHHae